# Bottom Unity launcher stops full screen video controls from working

Tags: unity, video, vlc, youtube, fullscreen

As much as I think having the launcher at the bottom is better, it seems to have a problem.  I can't control video such as youtube video when in full screen, because the launcher buttons seem to cover the youtube controls even if the launcher can't be seen.

The same happens with VLC.

Is it possible to fix this issue?